# Overlaying CAD drawing to Google Earth

Tags: georeferencing, google-earth, cad

I am trying to design a new road in Peru in a town called Lobitos. The area in question is shown below (extract from Google Earth).

[image: Image of the area of the new road]

From Google Maps I was able to pick out the exact road I am designing called Calle La Punta, along with a latitude and longitude of the road in question as shown below:-

[image: Google Maps]

I have drawn the proposed road in CAD using Cartesian XYZ coordinates as shown below:-

[image: CAD Drawing]

How do I align the coordinates of my CAD drawing so they corresponds to lat and lon values so that I can overlay my CAD drawing to Google Earth?

Comment: What CAD package are you using?